# Fill table from date range and parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table with different programs.

When the configuration of a program changes, an **event** is added into my DB with the new parameters.

It has several parameters : the datetime of the **event**, the number of days per week when it is active, the intensity, the start time and end time for each day.

I want to use these data to create a chart, but first I need to change the data to make them usable and understandable by the chart library I will use.

**What I want** is to create a table where I will have **everyday** my different programs and their parameters.

**Example of desired output :**

```
day        - program_code - intensity - start - end
01-01-2018 - 39           - 2         - 10    - 11
01-01-2018 - 40           - 4         - 14    - 15
02-01-2018 - 39           - 2         - 10    - 11
02-01-2018 - 40           - 4         - 14    - 15
The data stay the same until an event of configuration appears and changes 
the parameters, for example program 39 changes(40 stays the same) : 
03-01-2018 - 39           - 8         - 9     - 12
03-01-2018 - 40           - 4         - 14    - 15
```

And so everyday we have the active programs with their intensity and their start and end time.

(I've put the time in hour, but you see the idea).

Of course this will apply :

- On the number of days specified in the parameters
- And it will update when a new event shows up with the same program code

I am thinking to create a stored procedure with a temporary table to do that but I don't really know how to do it

*Note :* 
The number of day parameter works this way :

```
1 = Sunday  
2 = Monday
3 = Tuesday  
...
7 = Saturday  
8 = All week  
9 = Weekend
```

Code :

```
CREATE TABLE events 
( `program_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
`program_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
`days` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`intensity` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, 
`start` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, 
`end` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL);
INSERT INTO events (`program_code`, `program_datetime`, `days`, `intensity`, `start`, `end`) 
VALUES 
(40, '2018-03-05 13:24:31','8', '1', '75600', '82800'),
(39, '2018-03-05 13:24:15','8', '2', '57600', '75600'),
(40, '2018-03-02 04:34:51','9', '2', '75600', '82800'),
(39, '2018-03-02 04:34:17','1', '3', '57600', '75600'),
(37, '2018-02-18 14:31:25', '2', '2', '25200', '39600'),
(39, '2018-01-23 13:02:00','7', '4', '64800', '75600');
```

[DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uXkWkxCrRn1GZgHF4cXjhE/1)

Comment: Looks good to me. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I want values for **everyday** not just when the configuration changes